# Making hands-free calls

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, telephonymanager

In my application, I need to make a call to a number, but the call must be made hands-free. I tried many available methods, min the method from [this link](http://danielthat.blogspot.com/2013/06/android-make-phone-call-with-speaker-on.html).
The application logs showed the action of switching to hands-free, but physically it had no effect.

I also tried to do it with the help of such code:

```
private void enableHandsFree() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class audioSystemClass = Class.forName("android.media.AudioSystem");
        Method setForceUse = audioSystemClass.getMethod("setForceUse", int.class, int.class);
        // First 1 == FOR_MEDIA, second 1 == FORCE_SPEAKER. To go back to the default
        // behavior, use FORCE_NONE (0).
        setForceUse.invoke(null, 1, 1);
    }
```

Unfortunately also without success. Is there any way to handle such a problem?
Tested on Android 10

Answer (score 0):

Undocumented API calls have been progressively disallowed in the last few android versions. The code you posted may work on on older APIs (my guess would be <= 26), but it'll have no effect in the newer versions.

For security reasons, no app is allowed to control audio output used by other apps. The only app that can do that is the one that as audio focus. And you're specifically trying to control audio output of the Phone app

Comment: So is there no way to make such a call? I'm puzzled why there is no way, for example, to pass a parameter when calling that the call is to be made hands-free.

Comment: No, sorry -- there is no way